# Images and heap size Issue

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage

I am trying to crop 1000 images using Asprise cropping app.

The process is,first it downloads the image from Content Manager then crops the image and then upload the cropped image in Content Manager again.

I have created batch file to run this for 1000 images,
Initially it worked for 300 images and gave below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(
n Source)
        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.loops.MaskBlit$General.MaskBlit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.loops.Blit$GeneralMaskBlit.Blit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.blitSurfaceData(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageCopy(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.drawToBufImage(Unknown Source
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.copyImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
```

Then I increased the heap size to -Xmx728M the in worked for 500 + images and again same outofMemory error.

It throws the error on marked line

```
  private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
         if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
             return (BufferedImage)image;
         }

         image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();

             boolean hasAlpha = hasAlpha(image);

         BufferedImage bimage = null;
         GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
         try {
             int transparency = Transparency.OPAQUE;
             if (hasAlpha) {
                 transparency = Transparency.BITMASK;
             }

             GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
             GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
             bimage = gc.createCompatibleImage(
                 image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), transparency);
         } catch (HeadlessException e) {
             // The system does not have a screen
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         if (bimage == null) {
             // Create a buffered image using the default color model
             int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
             if (hasAlpha) {
                 type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
             }
             bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
         }


         Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();

         g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);      //error
         g.dispose();

      return bimage;
     }
```

What can I do to handle this problem?
How to free BufferedImage memory ?

I used

```
BufferedImageObj.flush();
BufferedImageObj=null;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, you got chance to solve this problem? i have the similar problem too in reading the images? It will be good, if you can help me out bye saying how have you sorted out this memory problem in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your error is not actually as a result of that line; rather I suspect that drawing the image pushes the program into the `OutOfMemory` state.

You generally can't hold that many images in memory at once. Remember that Java loads images at full resolution by default. I don't see it holding hundreds of images easily. Make sure you're only loading the ones you need at a given moment. Then, let the JVM garbage collect the memory by setting the image equal to null, when it's no longer needed.